# Feasibility of Actuator-Boosted Ammunition

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons

I was searching for better forms of ammunition across the net, which could replace the current standard types of ammunition, and I came across an interesting one on Deviantart, called **Jackhammer Ammunition**, by **KillSwitchWes**.

[image]

The user also gave a lovely description of what this bullet does, and how it mostly functions:

*"The Jackhammer (PRO-JH) round is a proprietary round designed by Opteron Armaments to create a round that would dominate over all other energy transfer rounds. The bullet has a soft, flat tip with a small hollow backed by a tungsten carbide plug. When striking an object the tip mushrooms out but not like a hollow point round, instead this squashes out to create a larger surface area much like a HESH tank round. A moment later the micro force actuator housed inside goes off sending about 3 times as much energy as the bullet itself through the squash tip and into the target for insane stopping power.*

*Opteron decided that standard propellants would not be sufficient in providing superior velocities over standard rounds so the Hyperion-Opteron R&D firm designed a new system of ignition. This shell casing uses electro-thermal ignition in combination with a new mix of solid propellant.
This system works by sending a high voltage pulse through the rear of the round, this explosively vaporizes the small rod through the center of the round and creates a plasma arc. This plasma ignites the ignition coating around the rod and efficiently burns the main propellant charge. All this helps to give the round a more consistent burn of the powder and increases the accuracy and power of the bullet."*

As I have seen, the propellant works on **Electrothermal-Chemical Technology**, already mostly acceptable to work. But what I am unsure about is how the Micro-Actuator will achieve its effect, and how it is triggered. This is what I would like clarification on.

To prove this bullet feasible, I just need to know how the Micro-Actuator could be triggered to release its effect, if at all.

Comment: Wouldn't the author of that material you quote know better than any of us?

Comment: What size is this thing? What is it supposed to be used against? And perhaps more importantly, what do you think a "micro-actuator" actually is, other than technobabble? The source doesn't explain it.

Comment: Um... More efficient burning of the powder. Ok. The limit on bullet velocity is probably the barrel of the gun.  http://www.frfrogspad.com/miscellb.htm  You could put more power in the bullet, but you can't put more than the barrel can support.  If you need more velocity than gunpowder can support you probably want some other kind of gun such as a rail gun.

Comment: Honestly sounds just like a HESH shell. Although I'm not 100% on this, i guess that the explosion is just triggered by a delayed (to allow the squash head to expand) impact fuse. That's your Micro-Actuator.

Comment: @StarfishPrime the problem with looking for engineering solutions on DeviantArt is that artists usually aren't engineers...

Answer (score 2):

The microactuator described above is a scaled-down version of a base of an impact fuze.
These are a combination of acceleration sensitive mechanical trigger with fulminating explosives to initiate the charge or rocket engine in this case

[image: cut away of base impact fuse]

The thumbtack looking affair in the diagram moves forward when the round comes to an abrupt halt -- impact -- and ignites the percussion cap which ignites the tiny rocket engine in the hypothetical round.